# Is there an easy way to decide the sign of $\sqrt x \ln (x + 1) - \sqrt {x + 1} \ln x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality

Is there an easy way to decide the sign of $\sqrt x \ln (x + 1) - \sqrt {x + 1} \ln x$?

The original problem is to decide when ${(n + 1)^{\sqrt n }}$ is greater than ${n^{\sqrt {n + 1} }}$.

It seems that the function is monotonic and has a unique root near $x=6.9$, but I wonder how to decide its sign explicitly since the derivative is a little bit complex.

Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Asymptotically though, you'll have a $\ln(n)$ factor in the expansion of $n^\sqrt{n+1}$ for $1$ in the other expansion so it is the greater of the two. But for small $n$ I agree the derivative is awfull.

Comment: Although not quite *"easy"*, I found a way. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: You can look at the function $\,x^{1/x}\,$ comparing $\,x_1^{1/x_1}\,$ with $\,x_2^{1/x_2}\,$ for $\,x_1:=\sqrt{x}\,$ and $\,x_2:=\sqrt{1+x}\,$ . The rest consists of elementary transformations.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider the function
$$f(y)=\frac{\log(y)}{\sqrt y}\implies f'(y)=-\frac{\log (y)-2}{2 y^{3/2}}$$ The derivative cancels when $y=e^2$ and it is positive for $0 < y < e^2$.

Now, use

$$\sqrt x \,\log (x + 1) - \sqrt {x + 1}\, \log (x)={\sqrt x\,\sqrt {x+1}}\left(\frac{\log(x+1)}{\sqrt {x + 1} }-\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt {x} }\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

When I plot it in Alpha it appears to be monotoniclly decreasing.  Given your original problem, you are really interested in its sign.  It changes from positive to negative at about $6.91$.  As a result, for $n \in \Bbb N$ we have $(n+1)^{\sqrt n} \gt n^{\sqrt{n+1}}$ for $n \le 7$.  The inequality reverses for $n \gt 7$

Comment: The original question asked whether the expression was monotonic.  It was only after my answer that it changed to determining the sign.